# Are the following transformations linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I'm preparing for my exam and I am stuck at these two exercises in which I must prove that the given transformatios are linear. I know that a transformation is linear, if it's closed under adition and scalar multiplication.

1)
A vector $\mathbf{a}$ is given in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let the transformation be defined in $A: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ as $Ax = \langle x,\mathbf{a}\rangle x$

Is this transformation linear?

2)
A transformation is defined in $T: \mathbb{R}_2[x]\to\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ as: $(T(p))(x) = x^2p(1/x)$. Prove, that it's linear and find it's transformation matrix in standard basis.

I know that, to find the transformation matrix, I have to find out where the transformation transforms vectors of the standard basis. I saw a similar example, where the values $\{1,x,x^2\}$ were simply inserted into the equation of the transformation, so this must be somewhat similar.

I thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a transformation to be linear? Also, I am unfamiliar with the notation R2[x]

Comment: *ALL* linear transformations are linear. Perhaps you want to ask "are the following transformations linear?" The context seems to say that. But I want to make sure you realize that the word linear does not always precede the word transformation.

Comment: I know how to prove, that it's linear (by showing that it's closed under adition and some scalar multiplication). The notation R2[x] denotes a space of polynomials of degree 2.

Comment: @all: Sorry, I overlooked that and hopefully corrected the question.

Comment: @rschwieb: I think you meant "the word 'transformation' is not always preceded by 'linear'". Because I'm sure that OP realises that the final word in the question title does not precede the word 'transformation'. :-)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen No, what I wrote is exactly what I meant, and is correct. It looks like you are looking at the current edit and not what used to be there.

Comment: @rschwieb: I wasn't talking about the question, but about your comment. Do you want to stick to "I want to make sure you realize that the word linear does not always precede the word transformation"? Even in the original question title the final "linear" did not precede anything (other than a question mark), in particular it did not precede the word "transformation". It is hard for me to imagine that OP did not realize that (but if you really insist, you are quite free to nevertheless worry about that eventuality).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The edit history shows the original question title was "Are the following linear transformations linear?" and the question in the body was the same. There is a "linear" preceding "transformation" in both cases. This is what my comment is about, and so I'm not sure what you are reading.

Comment: @rschwieb: This is really getting too silly. But read what you wrote, the subject of the phrase following "realize that" is "the word linear". Of this word you say that (you fear OP thinks) it "always precedes transformation". This is not the same as (thinking that) "the word transformation is always being preceded by the word linear", which I think is what you meant. Call me a nitpick (though I did throw in a smiley). It just goes to show that we all have difficulty in reading exactly what we wrote. I am certain that I'm no exception either.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen OK, I finally see the interpretation you were using. While "is always being preceded" would be an ungrammatical substitute here, I think you're right that "Y isn't always preceded by X" is what I really meant when I said "X doesn't always precede Y." To native speakers in everyday conversation, though, they will be considered equivalent. Sorry to have not seen it earlier. I overlooked the subtle point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

You must be using the notation $\,(t,r)\,$ to denote some inner product in $\,\Bbb R^3\,$ , most probably the usual euclidean one , so using the bilinearity of the inner product:

$$A(x+y):=(x+y,a)a=\left((x,a)+(y,a)\right)a=(x,a)a+(y,a)a=\ldots\\{}\\\forall\,\,k\in\Bbb R\;\;,\;\;A(kx):=(kx,a)a=k(x,a)a=\ldots$$

For (2):

$$T(p(x)+q(x)):=x^2\left(p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+q\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\ldots\\\forall\,k\in\Bbb R\;\;,\;\;T(kp(x)):=x^2\left(kp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=kx^2p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ldots$$